# Let a > 0 be a constant. Find a simplified, asymptotically tight bound for the recurrence T(n) = aT(n-2) + C

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, recurrence-relation

So I have read the posts on this site involving recurrence relations, however this problem is a little different, because of the constant a involved with the recursive portion. I'm trying to solve this recurrence relation by expanding it out and here is what I have so far:

[image]

I'm not sure where to go from here and how to find the asmpytotic bounds.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! 1. Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.  2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: Please specify the initial condition of the recurrence relation. What is the value of T(1) exactly. From what I can make out it is equal to _c_. Is this what it is?

Comment: There are $n/2$ terms and not $\log_2 n$ terms in the expansion. And why can't you do a sum on a geometric series? But your approach is correct.

Comment: Hi. So there are n/2 terms? And yes sorry T(1) here is equal to c. I was thinking a sum of geometric series, but im not sure how to go about doing that with the constant a. Would the aspytotic bound here just be a constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first four lines of your argument were correct; all you missed was the proper generalization. In general, we see that
$$
T(n) = c+c\alpha+c\alpha^2+\dotsb+c\alpha^{j-1}+\alpha^j T(n-2j)
$$
Now we want to drive $T(n-2j)$ down to a value we know, namely $T(1)=c$. To do this we'll need $n-2j=1$ and so we set $j=(n-1)/2$, giving us
$$\begin{align}
T(n) &= c+c\alpha+c\alpha^2+\dotsb+c\alpha^{j-1}+\alpha^j T(n-2j)\\
     &= c+c\alpha+c\alpha^2+\dotsb+c\alpha^{(n-1)/2-1}+\alpha^{(n-1)/2} c\\
     &= c(1+\alpha+\alpha^2+\dotsb+\alpha^{(n-1)/2})
\end{align}$$
and this is just a geometric series, so I'll leave the last steps to you.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to solve a modified recurrence in which there is no constant. Let $S(n) = T(n) - C/(1-\alpha)$. Then
$$
S(n) = T(n) - C/(1-\alpha) = C + \alpha T(n-2) - C/(1-\alpha) = \\ C + \alpha (S(n-2) + C/(1-\alpha)) - C/(1-\alpha) = \alpha S(n-2).
$$
(I found the constant $C/(1-\alpha)$ by solving linear equations.)

The solution to $S(n)$ with initial conditions $S(0),S(1)$ is easily found to be
$$
S(2n) = \alpha^n S(0), \qquad S(2n+1) = \alpha^n S(1).
$$
It follows that
$$
T(2n) = \alpha^n (T(0) - C/(1-\alpha)) + C/(1-\alpha), \\ T(2n+1) = \alpha^n (T(1) - C/(1-\alpha)) + C/(1-\alpha).
$$